# How to compare each row of a column to all the other row of the same column of a large dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, iteration

I have a dataframe which have two columns - unique_id and id_string.The dataframe looks likes:

```
| unique_id| id_string |
| -------- | --------- |
| 123      | abc       |
| 456      | pqr       |
| 789      | xyz       |
| 000      | lmn       |
```

I want to compare the id_string of each unique_id with the all the other id_string of the column.
I want the output to look like the table below:

```
| unique_id| id_string | duplicate_id|duplicate_string|score|
| -------- | --------- |-------------|----------------|-----|
| 123      | abc       |456          |pqr             |91   |
| 123      | abc       |789          |xyz             |92   |
| 123      | abc       |000          |lmn             |93   |
```

I have written a code using the for loop which is below:

```
out_put_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in   input_df.index:
    unique_id = input_df.at[i, 'unique_id']
    id_string = input_df.at[i, 'id_string']
    j = i+1
    for j in range(len(input_df.index)-j):
        dupicate_id = input_df.at[j, 'unique_id']
        duplicate_string = input_df.at[j, 'id_string']
        comparition_score = fuzz.token_set_ratio(id_string, duplicate_string)
        out_put_df = out_put_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'unique_id': unique_id,'id_string': id_string,'dupicate_id': dupicate_id,'duplicate_string': duplicate_string,'comparition_score': comparition_score}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

The original dataframe has half million rows, so it is taking infinite time. Can someone please tell me the optimum way to do this?. I come to know about it itertools.combinations , but I am unable to use it too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sorting. Sort by `id_string` column and iterate over all rows - whenever the next value in `id_string` column is equal to the current one - you have a duplicate. You can also look back (which might be easier) with the last value of `id_string`:

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame()
prev_id_string = None  # or some other invalid value that does not exist in your df
prev_unique_id = None
rows = []
for _, (unique_id, id_string) in input_df.sort_values(by=['id_string', 'unique_id']).iterrows():
    if prev_id_string == id_string:
        score = # calculate it as you wish
        row.append((prev_unique_id, prev_id_string, unique_id, score))

    prev_unique_id = unique_id    

out_put_df = pd.DataFrame(columns="unique_id, id_string, duplicate_id, duplicate_string, score".split(", "), data=rows)
```

Comment: how the code is identifying the prev_id_string? Initially we are defining it as None, then later we are doing if prev_id_string == id_string , so how it will check , its value is None ?

Comment: Fixed the issue - you should update it with every loop.